# Testing if one Pandas (Multi)Index is a subset of another

Tags: python, pandas

How can I test if one pandas (Multi)Index is a subset of another. The order doesn't matter, as long as the values exist.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df0 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(3,10), index=['foo', 'bar', 'baz'] )
df1 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(2,10), index=['baz', 'foo'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame( np.random.rand(3,10), index=['foo', 'baz', 'BLAH'] )

issubset(df0.index,  df1.index)  # True
issubset(df0.index,  df2.index)  # False
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `isin` and `all`:

```
df1.index.isin(df0.index).all()

True

df2.index.isin(df0.index).all()

False
```

Answer (score 1):

Try [set.issubset](http://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/sets/issubset.html), as in:

```
set(df1.index).issubset(set(df0.index)) # True
set(df0.index).issubset(set(df2.index)) # False
```

Because a [`pandas.Index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.html) is an (ordered) array, you want to convert it to an (unordered) set and then use `issubset`.